# Working out the structure of a website by spidering it

Tags: web-crawler, sitemap

When I'm refactoring a website I like to work out the existing structure to make sure I'm not missing anything when porting it over to a new navigation / menu system.

I often end up doing this by manually going over the site or stripping down a sitemap listing. The downside to a sitemap is that a Publications section could have thousands of links listed which then need manually pruning.

Do any automated tools exist that would generate a visual structure of the website on 1 page?

Answer (score 1):

The *Site Visualizer* can [generate a visual sitemap](http://site-visualizer.com/en/visual-sitemap) of a website.
Click *Project -> New*, set up spider settings, then click *Start* button to run the crawl.

After it is finished, click *Draw* button of the *Visual Sitemap* tab. You can highlight outbound links of a page by clicking on it. Use *Save* button to save the visual structure to an image file:

[image: visual sitemap generator]

But if the website is large enough, the visualization won't fit to one printer page. In this case a simple [list of website's pages](http://site-visualizer.com/en/pages-links) can help you. Go to *Pages & Links* tab, right-click on the top *Pages* table, choose *Select All*, then *Copy Rows with Headers*. After that paste the data into an *MS Excel* sheet or a similar application:
[image: website pages]

Site Visualizer has 30-day *fully-functional* trial period, so you can perform your task at no cost.

Answer (score -1):

I would recommend using Slickplan. You can create sitemaps from scratch or import and reorganize a sitemap from existing website using the site crawler.
Also it has integrated Google Analytics module that gives you the ability to display advanced metrics, so you can choose how to best redesign or reorganize your website.
This app has the 30 day free trial, so you can check it out.

I found this video tutorial on how their site crawler works:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YwWJt-jCnLM

Cheers!